# common subsequences of lists in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a predicate common(L, S) which from a list of lists L generates in S all common subsequences of the lists in L.

```
subseq([], _).
subseq([H|S], L) :- append(_, [H|T], L), subseq(S, T).


common(L, X) :- not((
        member(A, L),
        not(subseq(X, A))
       )).
```

It just gives me 'true' even with wrong input.

For example:

`common([[1,2,3,4], [2,3], [12]], X).
true`

**Edit**

I've noticed that it's actually working but it's just not substituting X with the term for which the predicate is true.

Comment: What do you mean with `'yes'`? Can you give the exact query? Furthermore that is logical: negation in Prolog is not constructive. So it will either return true or false.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I've edited the post adding an example query.

Comment: Furthermore you want *all* common subsequences? Because that is a hard problem (in terms of computational complexity). Please specify with a few examples (input and expected output what you aim to do).

Comment: My expectation is for example

`common([[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5]], X).
X = [2]
X = [2,3]
X = [2,3,4]
X = [3, 4]
X = [4]`

Comment: I know it might be a hard problem, but I don't think that's a problem since the idea is to write a generator, which generates the result in the second argument of the predicate.

Comment: Please note that a [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) is something different! What you want is called a substring or sublist.

Comment: Thanks, I have forgotten that. But even after changing the definition of subseq to `subseq([], _). subseq([H|S], L) :- append(_, [H|T], L), subseq(S, T).` It still behaves the same way. I've noticed that it's working properly when I give it exact values, but when trying to substitute X with the result it doesn't work. It just gives 'yes'

Comment: And why not `X = [3]`?

Comment: Yes, whatever, that too. I think the idea was clear enough even without an example.

Comment: `not/1` succeeds if the query argument is not provable. It's not a good generator of results. And `common/2` always succeeds because (1) if `L` is empty, then `member(A, L)` is not provable, so not(member(A, L), ...)` succeeds, and (2) if `L` has list elements, then `member(A, L)` succeeds for some `A`, and `subseq(A, X)` succeeds, so `not(subseq(A, X))` fails, and so `member(...), not(subseq(A, X))` is not provable. Finally, if `L` has elements that aren't lists, then `member(A, L)` fails and `not(member...)` succeeds.

Answer (score 9):

A substring is a non-empty prefix of a suffix.

```
substring_of(Ys, Xs) :-
   Ys = [_|_],           %  a non-empty
   append(_, Zs, Xs),    %                       a suffix of Xs
   append(Ys, _, Zs).    %             prefix of 

common(Xss, Xs) :-       % Xs is a substring of each element of Xss
   maplist(substring_of(Xs), Xss).

?- common([[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5]], Xs).
   Xs = [2]
;  Xs = [2,3]
;  Xs = [2,3,4]
;  Xs = [3]
;  Xs = [3,4]
;  Xs = [4]
;  false.
```